# Which DAO Cursor and LockType Is Suitable for not Showing Other Users' Deletion in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, dao, recordset

I need to find a DAO cursor and lock type in VBA Access that allows me to hide other users' deleted recordset such that I can open a recordset for reading, let it open on the secreen. then, another user deletes this same recordset and, back on my computer this open recordset get moved to the next valid recordset or I can trap this recordset deletion event and splash a message on the screen. is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Access tables, or linked tables to another database such as SqlServer? If you're using Access tables, it will show you that a record's been deleted like this:

Before deletion on another computer:

[image]

After a user on another computer deleted a record:

[image]

With Access tables, your form is informed that the record has been deleted and automatically tells you onscreen, but if you're using linked tables, you may not get the message back that a record's been deleted, so in that case you may need to do timed polling of the database to see if there have been any changes, if you want this change to appear in real-time.

Comment: hi James. what I want is to lock the current recordset avoiding 2 users editing the same one. imagine an Employee register. 2 users open the same employee register, eg, John's register. user 1 is reading, user 2 deletes it. then I want to warn user 1 with a message instead of showing all the bound fields of the form with the value "#Deleted". if you know how, I'd appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: I intend to use linked tables. all the front-ends linked to 1 back-end.

Comment: Hmm, you'd probably need some kind of timer behind the scenes which polls the database to see if the record being viewed has been updated or deleted. With linked tables I don't think you can get the database to tell you there's been a change without explicitly using code to query it. It's definitely doable but just involves the coding.